# Make it easier to find what you want

Tags: feature-request, design

I am really annoyed by how little screen space is used for a question or actual content when I am not logged in to sites on the network.

I visited an AskUbuntu question and found less than 10% of the screen currently in view was what I actually wanted to see. With max resolution on my computer.

[image]

My view while looking at this page (and I'm sure many other people's view as well) is *"I came here for answers to my question, not finding a Dream Job, not Signing Up and not joining a Developers Team."*

I am posting this here rather than AskUbuntu Meta because most other sites (if not all of them) have the same clutter.

[image]

[image]

This needs to be fixed fast. Make the stuff a lot of viewers won't care about less intrusive.

If you have a look at my [profile description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/460489/james-douglas?tab=profile), you'll see how much I dislike distractions on these sites

Comment: Not just anonymous users though; I also wan't to see less gubbins.

Comment: And while I am a "New contributor" on meta.SE, I am not on [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7733026/james-douglas)

Comment: "New" in this case encompasses all not-logged users :)

Comment: MSO dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357858/dont-clutter-half-the-screen-with-things-most-people-dont-care-for (Both this one and the one on MSE are wrongly marked as planned, since the one who posted that left SE, I highly doubt there are any plans to ever change it)

Comment: You'll find that logging in and using an adblocker will almost completely eliminate all of the clutter. Yes, it's a problem, but you do have solutions available to you.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Yes or you could use extentions like Stylish or Styling to remove them, but I am more worried about the impression that the site is going to give to new viewers. If they can see very little of the question and most of the screen is signup form, they might think they need to sign up to use the site.

Comment: They _do_ have to sign up on some sites, Stack Overflow in particular. But I take your point, and I agree it's not a great first impression.

Comment: @ArtOfCode But even on Stack Overflow they don't need to sign up to view the question